# Javascript Shorthand for assigning name value pair to object

Tags: javascript

When adding name value pairs to a new object:

```
function example() {

   var address = {}; //I'd like to omit this line somehow, is it possible?
   var values = ["Dog", "Cat", "Giraffe", "Monkey", "Goose"]
   for (i=0; i <5; i++) {

      address[i] = values[i]

   }

}
```

Is there any shorthand that allows me to omit the line commented above?

Comment: Where do `key` and `value` come from?

Comment: Why would you want to omit that? If you want a "*new object*", you'll need say so. What's your actual problem?

Comment: Is there a way to do it one line?

Comment: @Andrew, do what? you can do `var address = { key1:1, key2:2 ,...}` and it would be one line

Comment: For example, if I wanted to assign something to a new variable called "newArrayHolder" , I could do var newArrayHolder = existingArray || [];

Comment: why are you implicitly converting address as an object into address as an array?

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a clever way to write the above to save one line in code, that's all. Not trying to achieve anything in terms of functionality. The array to object was just a crudely crafted example.

Comment: @Andrew do you want to copy array's content to the new `object`? Or just copy an array as is without converting to an object?

Comment: for provided code you **can not** avoid this line

Comment: I would like assign name value pairs to an object, without the var address= {} line. If this is not possible, then nevermind. The for loop is just a crudely constructed example. The reason is because in PHP for example, you can construct associated arrays by doing $var[] = $fakevalue. No need to first say $var = []. Just curious as to whether something like that exists for objects in javascript.

Comment: @Andrew javascript does not have associative array, so strange expect from object, behavior as from array.

Comment: @Andrew its possible but not in the above example. You cab create var address = {"key":"value"}. no need of var address[], or if you have another array you can do var address = tempArray

Answer (score 0):

You can create that type of array using object or array literal grammar, or object/array methods.

An array of arrays:

```
// Using array literal grammar
var arr = [[value1, value2, value3], [value1, value2]]

// Creating and pushing to an array
var arr = [];
arr.push([value1, value2, value3]);
```

An object of arrays:

```
  // Using object literal grammar
    var obj = { "key": [value1, value2, value3], "key2": [value1, value2] } 

    // Creating object properties using bracket or dot notation
    var obj = {};
    obj.key = [value1, value2, value3];
    obj["key2"] = [value1, value2];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an alternative way to do exactly what your example is doing, you can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).  If you understand how it works, then it is a lot cleaner in my opinion.

```
var vals = ["Dog", "Cat", "Giraffe", "Monkey", "Goose"];

function assignNameVal(arr){
    return arr.reduce(function(prev, curr, index, array){ 
      prev[index] = curr;        // curr is each element in arr for each iteration
      return prev;               // returned value is the prev arg for next execution in iteration
    }, {});                      // {} is first value of prev
}
```